# Error 405 - Method not allowed with IIS Express 10 with CORS for Web API

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, cors, iis-express

I know this question has been asked plenty of times, each with similar answers, but after hours on this problem, I've yet to get it resolved, so I'm hoping additional suggestions may be provided.

I'm getting `Error 405 - Method not allowed`

1. I've removed the `WebDAV` entries from the module and handler section as suggested.
2. I've also changed the `ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0`. Removed it first as suggested but didn't work so re-added it but with a slightly different definition `<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." 
          verb="GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" 
          type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
          preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />` 
   where each verb is defined rather than using `*`
3. I've ensure CORS was enabled i.e. `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);` is called from my Startup class in `public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)`
4. `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` has been set in my web.config

The weird thing is that it works just fine for `DELETE` but not for `PUT`.

Here's my `System.WebServer` section from my web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
        </modules>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" 
                       value="GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <handlers>
        <clear/>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="WebDAV" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." 
             verb="GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE"
             type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
             preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

When I run Fiddler, I'm getting the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: GET,POST
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcU3BpbmRldlxXb3JrXEpvaWZmTGlzdGluZ05lnM=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE
Date: Mon, 15 Jul 2019 23:41:32 GMT
Content-Length: 79
{
  "message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."
}
```

As you can see, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` appears to be set correctly but the `Allow:` is still set to `GET,POST`. Why is that? Where am I suppose to change this to have all the verbs?

And finally my action in my web controller is defined as follows:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("id:{Guid}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateCompany(Guid id)
{
}
```

Pretty standard stuff!

Any ideas and/or suggestions? Remember that I'm concentrating on getting this to work on IIS Express. Once I've got that resolved, I'll check it out in IIS but I really want to get to the bottom of this first.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE-1**

I've just found an article from Microsoft regarding CORS, and even thought I'm enabling it as mentioned above, I've noticed that I don't have any references in my list of references to `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` which is odd and when I try to add the `[EnableCors...]` attribute, no references are shown which would indicate even more clearly that it may not be installed properly or at all.

I'll check that tomorrow and update.

I've also forgot to mention that OWIN is installed and set up. In the event this may give more clues as to why I still can't resolve this problem.

**UPDATE-2**

My add company (POST) is defined as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddCompany (
    CompanyRequestDto companyRequestDto)
{
}
```

My update company (PUT) is defined as follows:

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateCompany (
    Guid Id,
    CompanyRequestDto companyRequestDto)
{
}
```

and my WebApiConfig.cs has the following route defined in it:

```
// Web API routes
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I've removed `[Route("id:{Guid}")]` as I thought it could have been that, but it's not. Same issue.

As Andrei Dragotoniu suggested, commenting out my UpdateCompany function generated the very same error which means another function is being hit but I have no idea which one as none of the breakpoints I've put are being hit, nor, any of them are defined as PUT so it's confusion. I'm sure we'll get to the bottom of it.

**UPDATE-3**

I feel really stupid right now!! After wasting so much time researching this problem, it actually wasn't there! Unlike a POST request where you only post the object, the PUT request expected a CompanyId as part of the query string which I had omitted and cause the problem!

http://localhost:12345/Companies

instead of

http://localhost:12345/Companies/61770BAA-78A6-E911-AEB1-001A7DDA7111

Anyway, I'm glad I'm up and running and I hope nobody else will do something as silly as this but if you do, hopefully, this will help!

Comment: The request method that 405 is in response to is the OPTIONS method. Your browser is making a CORS preflight OPTIONS request. The preflight fails, so the browser stops right there, and so never even moves on to attempting the PUT or POST or whatever method your frontend JavaScript code is trying to send.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Isn't that ` <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" 
                       value="GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />` taking care of this?

Comment: @sideshowbarker I'm currently reading this `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api`, hopefully it will shed some light.

Comment: No, the `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />` part does not take care of the handling which is causing that 405. The only effect that `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />` part has is to cause the server to send back an `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE` response header.

Comment: ok, thanks for clarifying this. I'm using OWIN.Cors btw which I probably should have mentioned and while I've just tried a custom solution to enable each individual `Methods`, I noticed that I already had an entry in my configuration with `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll); // enable CORS origin requests` and it is set to AllowAll. Maybe this does not include PUT. I'll research it further in a sec.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Sorry about this! But I stupidly missed the fact that when I do a PUT request, I was suppose to provide the ID as part of the URL!! Thanks again for taking the time and apologies!

Answer (score 2):

Do not do this on IIS Express, that's pointless. Get it working in proper IIS instead.

One thing to check, the error method tells you that the particular method you're accessing does not support PUT. This doesn't mean that the PUT verb is not enabled in config. What it means is that the particular method you're accessing does not support it.

You need to check and see which endpoint is being hit because it doesn't seem to be the one you think. Check your rules basically. Remember they get applied in order so you really want your most concrete ones to be loaded first and the most general one at the end.

One quick way to check this is to comment out the `UpdateCompany(Guid id)` endpoint and see if you still get the same response when you repeat the call in Postman. If you do, then it's obvious that your request is being handled by a different endpoint, not the one you think.

Comment: @The reason I'm using IIS Express is that I'm not able to debug when running directly in IIS which is a pain. I did what you suggested i.e. comment out the UpdateCompany(Guid id) and surprisingly, as you suggested, I got the same error. I'm not sure which other method is being handled as this is the only PUT I have in my Controller. I've put a breakpoint on all other actions, and none are being triggered. The way I've defined url is as follows: {{url}}/api/companies and the same url is used by both the CreateCompany (POST) and UpdateCompany (PUT) and I thought this was the way to do it, no?

Comment: I'm so #$!#$ bind!! All this time, it was staring at me in the face. The PUT request was throwing this error because... you're ready for this... I did not pass the CompanyId as part of my URL!!! I feel so stupid right now and wasted so much time and I was concentrating with problem in the web API when it was the URL that was badly formed all along... So sorry!!